# How to Authenticate User Against ADFS from my Custom SSO applicaiton

Tags: model-view-controller, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

i m little confused.i m creating a single sign on application for my applications.so the flow is when user try to access Login Controller of  example.com i m redirecting user to my SSO application

```
 FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RedirectToIdentityProvider("example.com", "example.com", true);
```

and  in this application i m showing a login page where user can input UserName and Password.So now i want  to authenticate User on the basis of these credentials from my ADFS.But i m confused how to do it

this  my Login Page

```html
@using SingleSignOn.Models

@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm(new { returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="left">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Username)
    </div>

    <div class="left">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>

    <div class="left"></div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
}
```

Here is my Post Method which is using  Form Authentication but i have to Use ADFS authentication here.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginModel loginModel, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (loginModel.Username == "user" && loginModel.Password == "password")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginModel.Username, true);
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The username or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        return View(loginModel);
    }
```

This my Index Method where want to receive Claims sign in User and then Redirect to example.com

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var action = Request.QueryString[Action];

            if (action == SignIn)
            {
                var formData = ProcessSignIn(Request.Url, (ClaimsPrincipal)User);
                return new ContentResult() { Content = formData, ContentType = "text/html" };
            }
            else if (action == SignOut)
            {
                ProcessSignOut(Request.Url, (ClaimsPrincipal)User, (HttpResponse)HttpContext.Items["HttpResponse"]);
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ADFS does not allow a custom login page. ADFS itself provides the login page when you redirect to it and returns after successful authentication with a SAML token.

This [example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sakamati/2015/07/06/creating-owin-based-ws-federation-application/) is for Azure AD but illustrates the principles.

Just use the ADFS metadata address.